# Conditional Formatting - Turning AhKs into A♥K♠

Tags: excel, formatting, poker, excel-2013

Basically I have a column showing poker hands data in the following form:

AsKh
TcTd
QsQh
5d7d

I want to apply a conditional formatting formulat to the column so that diamonds 'd' gets replaced with a blue diamond symbold and their preceding card gets colored blue. And so forth with all cards. The goal is to make it easier to read the data.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll probably want to use some sort of macro to split the formatting with the cell between symbol and regular font, with a substitute function to turn c, h, d... into char(167), char(168), ...

Comment: Yeah I could definetely split the column into more. Why are you suggesting four columns? Letter | Suit | Letter | Suit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula in a cell formatted with the symbol font. J and Q will look funky though. You'll have to use a macro to address that and basically adjust the font for each cell of the result.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"c",CHAR(167)),"h",CHAR(169)),"s",CHAR(170)),"d",CHAR(168))
```